Downloading satellite raster data using Earth Engine lib in Python
I'm using the following code to download satellite imagery for the given polygon. The script runs successfully,  but I don't get the files downloaded in the drive. What could be the reason?
 import ee
 import os
 from datetime import datetime

 try:
     ee.Initialize()
 except Exception as e:
     ee.Authenticate()
     ee.Initialize()


 def download_satellite_images(region_coords, start_date, end_date, download_folder, cloud_cover=10):


roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(region_coords)


collection = (
    ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
    .filterBounds(roi)
    .filterDate(start_date, end_date)
 .filter(ee.Filter.lt("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", cloud_cover))
)


image_list = collection.toList(collection.size())
image_count = image_list.size().getInfo()

if image_count == 0:
    print("No images found for the specified criteria.")
    return

print(f"Found {image_count} images. Starting download...")


os.makedirs(download_folder, exist_ok=True)


for i in range(image_count):
    image = ee.Image(image_list.get(i))
    image_id = image.id().getInfo()
    image_date = image.date().format("YYYY-MM-dd").getInfo()
    filename = f"{image_date}_{image_id}.tif"
    filepath = os.path.join(download_folder, filename)

    
    task= ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(
        image=image.clip(roi),
        description=filename,
        folder=download_folder,
        scale=10,  
        region=roi.getInfo()["coordinates"],
        fileFormat="GeoTIFF",
    )

    task.start()
    print(f"Started download task for {filename}")

 if __name__ == "__main__":

     region_coordinates = [
    [78.547606, 11.670881],
    [78.583869, 11.670881],
    [78.583869, 11.649485],
    [78.547606, 11.649485],
    [78.547606, 11.670881],
] 

start_date = "2024-06-01"
end_date = "2024-12-01"
download_dir = "satellite_images"

download_satellite_images(
    region_coords=region_coordinates,
    start_date=start_date,
    end_date=end_date,
    download_folder=download_dir,
    cloud_cover=10,
)

The output:
Found 11 images. Starting download...
Started download task for 2024-06-01_20240601T050649_20240601T051727_T44PKU.tif
Started download task for 2024-06-16_20240616T050701_20240616T051417_T43PHN.tif... so on

Well, since tasks are asynchronous, it's necessary to check for their status to better understand what's happening. Getting status of Google Earth Engine task shows how to get it in details, but in short ee.data.listOperations() may be used to better address the solution.
